# What makes repeated base64 and base36 encoding so slow? and how to make it faster?

Tags: python, encoding, base64, processing-efficiency, base32

I was trying out some different encodings and as I tried to encode some text repeatedly in base64/base32 (which one is used depends on a semi-random boolean list) I noticed that it was ridiculously slow which I didn't understand because I thought that they were particularly fast. I can't really figure out why it's so slow, it'd be cool if you could help me.

This is the part of the code concerned :

```py
from base64 import b64encode, b32encode
from random import random as rn

big_number = int(input("The number of encoding layers : "))
bool_list = [True if rn() < 0.5 else False for _ in range(big_number)]
sample_text = bytes("lorem ipsum", "utf8")
for curr_bool in bool_list:
    temp = b64encode(sample_text) if curr_bool else b32encode(sample_text)
    sample_text = temp
```

Comment: You say "so slow" as if you had told us how slow..

Comment: If you encode bytes with base64, the result is longer than the input. If you take this result and encode it again in a loop, you have exponential growth.

Comment: @Wups Your comment doesn't look like you're asking for more information, suggesting improvements, or avoiding answering the question...

Comment: @KellyBundy You're right, but I think the comment is not detailed enough for an answer. I see it more as a hint.

Comment: @KellyBundy sorry if my question wasn't very understandable, it is my first on this site. As for the "so slow", I couldn't have said because I hadn't timed the really long ones as I'd never witnessed them finish the calculations lol. After some research I've found that this encoding enlarges the byte-size by approximately 25% and as the comment from Wups says, it grows exponentially, rapidly outgrowing any realistic calculations. Thanks for your feedback though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory and time expensive operations. The answer is based on pivotal [comment (by Wups)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71009943/what-makes-repeated-base64-and-base36-encoding-so-slow-and-how-to-make-it-faste#comment125529252_71009943):

> If you encode bytes with `base64`, the result is longer than the
> input. If you take this result and encode it again in a loop, you have
> exponential growth.

The following modified script shows growing ratio for `base64` and `base32` encodings:

```
from base64 import b64encode, b32encode
from random import random as rn
ii = 0
big_number = int(input("The number of encoding layers : "))
30
bool_list = [True if rn() < 0.5 else False for _ in range(big_number)]
sample_text = bytes("lorem ipsum", "utf8")
sample_len = len( sample_text )
current_len = sample_len
for curr_bool in bool_list:
    sample_text = b64encode(sample_text) if curr_bool else b32encode(sample_text)
    print( ii, curr_bool, len(sample_text), (len( sample_text )/current_len))
    current_len = len( sample_text )
    ii += 1
```

** Sample output** (truncated): `python .\SO\71009943.py`

```
The number of encoding layers : 30
…
24 True 172320 1.3333333333333333
25 False 275712 1.6
26 True 367616 1.3333333333333333
27 False 588192 1.600017409470752
28 True 784256 1.3333333333333333
29 False 1254816 1.6000081606006202
```

So resultant length is roughly somewhere between [Compound interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest) for base64's `4/3` and base32's `1.6`:

```
big_number = 30
round( sample_len * (4/3) ** big_number)
# 61596
round( sample_len * 1.6 ** big_number)
# 14621508
```

and for a bigger numbers:

```
big_number = 50
round( sample_len * (4/3) ** big_number)
# 19423591
round( sample_len * 1.6 ** big_number)
# 176763184868
```

and

```
big_number = 99
round( sample_len * (4/3) ** big_number)
# 25723354884215
round( sample_len * 1.6 ** big_number)
# 1775296791184759324672
```

Comment: @KellyBundy  Answer updated. I can agree that the script takes a few seconds for `40` and becomes significantly slower for `42+` (in my box with poor 8GB operating memory). However, estimation for both growing ratios are kept…